# How can I keep my code synced to both a Git and SVN repository?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

At work I own a relatively small software tool (~25k lines of java), and I have been using a Git repo to revision it. Now the tool is going to be part of a larger package that is maintained in a totally different environment by other people, which uses SVN. But I still want to maintain the flexibility of my Git repo, so that I am not rigidly tied to the larger package's release schedule.

Is there a way I can keep my local area in sync with both revision control systems in a way that avoids uploading `.svn` files to git, and `.git` files to SVN? Ideally I'd want to keep committing the minor edits to Git, and then periodically push to SVN when requested, all from the same directory. Or am I doomed to keep copying files between two directories on my system?

Comment: use git svn...see the help docs by googling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is probably to use [`git-svn`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html). This allows you to use `git` as a frontend for a Subversion repository.

The simplest way to do this would be:

- create a SVN repository for the software (or use an existing repo)
- commit the software to SVN once (as a bunch of folders, using `svn commit`)
- use `git svn clone` to fetch the software as a git repository

The disadvantage is that you lose the git history you have created so far.

If you want to keep the git history, things will get a bit more complex (because SVN cannot represent some aspects of git's history, particularly branches). Basically you'd:

- create an empty SVN repo
- check it out using `git svn clone`
- import your existing git commits into this git repo
- push them to the SVN repo (`git svn dcommit`)

The "import your existing git commits" is where things will get tricky (for example, you will have to rebase on top of the initial commit in the `git svn` repo, then `git svn dcommit` will rebase again, which will play havoc with merge commits. However, if you can live with e.g. branches not being represented totally faithfully, you should be fine.